# Collapse more empty spaces in a string into single empty space in Java?

Tags: java

I have strings in the following form:

let the character - denote empty space

```
----100----100----1000---
```

that is, more empty spaces followed by a number, followed by more empty spaces followed by number, etc.
I need to extract the three numbers only. How do I do that in java?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To collapse the spaces (the question asked):

```
String collapsed = str.replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

---

To extract the 3 numbers (the question alluded to):

```
String[] numbers = str.trim().split(" +");
```

Comment: The OP wants to extract the numbers.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM I was getting there :)

Comment: The OP asked two things: to collapse the spaces in the title, and to extract the numbers in the text ... This answers the title :-)

Comment: @Matteo It answers both doesn't it? (Maybe refresh your browser)

Answer (score 7):

> I need to extract the three numbers only. How do I do that in java?

So I understand your string is like below, in which case you can split it on white spaces:

```
String str = "   100   100   1000";
String[] numbers = str.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Won't this give you a leading blank element?

Comment: 2nd place for that :) And how come I answered first, and your answerr was wrong, but you got the votes? You must have better charisma... +1 for that :)

Answer (score 0):

simply try using,

```
String newstring = oldstring.replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

or

```
String[] selected = oldstring.trim().split(" +");
```

Comment: "I need to extract the three numbers only."